# Check if instance of class exists with certain property

Tags: c#

I have a list of classes, each with four properties:

```
public class BroncoClass
{
    public NPC npc { get; set; }
    public int TimeLeft { get; set; }
    public bool Gravity { get; set; }
    public bool Rotation { get; set; }
}
public List<BroncoClass>  BroncoList = new List<BroncoClass>();
```

I want to check if the list contains a class with a specific npc value, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Main.npc.Length; i++) // For every alive npc
{
        if(BroncoList.contains a class where npc == Main.npc[i])
        {
        }
}
```

Haven't been able to find an answer online, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to keep the objects in a collection somewhere that you can query. Do you have a list of `BroncoClass` objects somewhere?

Comment: Well, you're going to want to check directly against the `npc` property of an actual instance...

Comment: In order to do that, you would need to keep track of all instances of a class that have been created (and that are still useful).  The framework actually does this under the covers (kind of-sort of) in order to decide if an instance/object is garbage.  But, in your code, if you want to do this, you'll need to keep track of what you are doing.

Comment: Can you edit the question to make what you are trying to achieve clearer? Where are you searching for this isntance - inside some collection like a list? Or are you trying to check if there is any instance in the entire program that has this value?

Comment: You could simply use this condition: `BroncoList.Any(b => b.npc == Main.npc[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *real* solution is to just keep a collection somewhere and use LINQ to query it. Presumably this collection would be easy to maintain as it would be the collection that is used for all other operations with `BroncoClass`.

**After update to OP...**
You already have the list, just use `list.Any(o => o.npc == testNpc)` or whatever other predicate you may need.

### However, if you *really* want to do the actual question:

Sounds like a reasonable usage of a factory pattern; **but** you will need to effectively do manual memory management. Your factory would be something like:

```
// Could be static, but I hate static. Don't use static.
public class BroncoFactory
{
     private List<BroncoClass> trackedObjects = new List<BroncoClass>();
     public BroncoClass New()
     {
         var newInstance = new BroncoClass();
         trackedObjects.Add(newInstance)
     }

     // Don't forget to call this or you'll leak!
     public void Free(BroncoClass instance)
     {
          trackedObjects.Remove(instance);
     }

     public bool ExistsWithNPC(NPC test)
     {
         return trackedObjects.Any(o => o.npc == test);
     }
}
```

Just really, really don't forget to call `Free` on an object when you are done with it.

Comment: Another option would be to keep a list of `WeakReference<BroncoClass>` to make the Free unnecessary, but that's getting a bit more tricky and requires more work to use properly.

Comment: @DanBryant That's a good call, I don't have enough experience with `WeakReference` to make a good answer based on it though

Comment: amazing overkill. HE has a list already called BroncoList. He just needs to know about linq.Any

Comment: @pm100 That was added after I wrote this. The original was "any instance in the program."

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for your time, I'll play around with it

Comment: @pm100 Which is why we discourage "chameleon" questions here. We should probably roll it back or at least mention the original

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: But, the OP modified his question (and made it more clear) in response to the intial comments.  Isn't that how it's supposed to work.  Though both answers (mine and yours) are overkill for the edited question, they do tell the OP how he could implement what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Flydog57 There's a fine line between "clarified" and "asked totally different question." IMO this one crossed that line, but I don't feel strongly enough about it to actually make the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @BradleyDotNET's answer.  I just folded the factory into the class as static methods.  I'm not saying this is right way to go, I'm just offering it as a solution to your question.  Using static methods in the class seems closer to what the OP is asking about.

First, I needed an NPC class to get this to compile.  Notice that it implements `IEquatable` so that I can compare instances for equality the way I want to (and that I override `GetHashCode` because that's a requirement).

```
public class NPC : IEquatable<NPC>
{
    private static int _indexKeeper = 0;
    public int Index { get; } = _indexKeeper++;

    public bool Equals(NPC other)
    {
        return Index == other?.Index;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Index.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

With that, here's the BroncoClass (mostly untested):

```
public class BroncoClass
{
    private BroncoClass(int timeLeft, bool gravity, bool rotation)
    {
        Npc = new NPC();
        TimeLeft = timeLeft;
        Gravity = gravity;
        Rotation = rotation;
    }
    public NPC Npc { get; set; }
    public int TimeLeft { get; set; }
    public bool Gravity { get; set; }
    public bool Rotation { get; set; }

    private static List<BroncoClass> _instances = new List<BroncoClass>();
    public static BroncoClass Create(int timeLeft, bool gravity, bool rotation)
    {
        var bronco = new BroncoClass(timeLeft, gravity, rotation);
        _instances.Add(bronco);
        return bronco;
    }

    public static bool Remove(NPC npc)
    {
        var broncoFound = _instances.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Npc == npc);
        if (broncoFound == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _instances.Remove(broncoFound);
        return true;
    }

    public static BroncoClass Find(NPC npc)
    {
        return _instances.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Npc == npc);
    }

}
```

Comment: @prn100: But, his initial question didn't have the list in it.  In the edited version, he has a list.  The reason both answers include creating a list is that that is a required feature.  We both showed how to create and maintain the list.  We both use LINQ to peak inside that list.

Comment: @Flydog57 I had confused myself in the original post, thanks for your reply I appreciate it.

Comment: @Declan: Note that you are probably going to want to implement `IEquatable` in your `NPC` class so you can control what equality means.  Also note that you can up-vote more than one response.

Comment: @Flydog57 Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.